# Ruby: methods as array elements - how do they work?

Tags: ruby

This probably isn't something you should try at home, but for some reason or another I tried to create an array of methods in Ruby.

I started by defining two methods.

```
irb(main):001:0> def test1
irb(main):002:1>   puts "test!"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> def test2
irb(main):005:1>   puts "test2!"
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
```

The weird thing happens when you try to put it into an actual array. It seems to run both methods.

```
irb(main):007:0> array = [test1, test2]
test!
test2!
=> [nil, nil]
```

And afterwards, the array is empty.

```
irb(main):008:0> puts array


=> nil
```

Can someone explain to me why it runs the methods? Other than that the whole excercise is seriously in need of an exorcist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you're storing in your array is the result of calling your methods, not the methods themselves.

```
def test1
  puts "foo!"
end

def test2
  puts "bar!"
end
```

You can store references to the actual methods like this:

```
> arr = [method(:test1), method(:test2)]
# => [#<Method: Object#test1>, #<Method: Object#test2>]
```

Later, you can call the referenced methods like this:

```
> arr.each {|m| m.call }
foo!
bar!
```

Comment: Oh, so it is possible. Nice!

Answer (score 9):

@alestanis explained the reason well.  If you were trying to store the methods, then you can do what Lars Haugseth says or you could do the folllowing:

```
test1 = Proc.new { puts "test!" }
test2 = Proc.new { puts "test2!" }
a = [test1, test2]
```

This may make your code much more readable.

Here is an irb run.

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > test1 = Proc.new { puts "test!" }
 => #<Proc:0x00000002798a90@(irb):9> 
1.9.3p194 :010 > test2 = Proc.new { puts "test2!" }
 => #<Proc:0x00000002792988@(irb):10> 
1.9.3p194 :011 > a = [test1, test2]
 => [#<Proc:0x00000002798a90@(irb):9>, #<Proc:0x00000002792988@(irb):10>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a `square` method and wanted to create an array with the square values of 2 and 4, you would write

```
array = [square(2), square(4)]
```

Here you are doing exactly the same thing, except that your test methods don't return anything and that's why your final `array` seems empty (actually, it contains `[nil, nil]`).

Comment: Method definitions in this case return `nil`, as is shown. The OP is wrong in saying that it became empty; it isn't. Blank lines were printed representing the two instances of `nil` that the array has.

Comment: @sawa You are right, my answer wasn't precise enough. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your array never contains anything else than two nil values. I tricks you by putting the strings when evaluating. But the return value of each function still is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs the two methods because you're actually calling the methods when you say "test1" and "test2" - parentheses are optional for ruby method calls.

Since both of your methods just contain a "puts", which returns nil, your resulting array is just an array of two nils.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my two-pennies worth. Building on the solutions already posted, this is an example of a working example. What might be handy for some here is that it includes method arguments and the use of `self` (which refers to the instance of the PromotionalRules class when it is instantiated) and the array of symbols, which is neat - I got that from the Ruby docs on the #send method [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send). Hope this helps someone!

```
class PromotionalRules
  PROMOTIONS = [:lavender_heart_promotion, :ten_percent_discount]

  def apply_promotions total, basket
    @total = total

    if PROMOTIONS.count > 0
      PROMOTIONS.each { |promotion| @total = self.send promotion, @total, basket }
    end

    @total.round(2)
  end

  def lavender_heart_promotion total, basket
    if two_or_more_lavender_hearts? basket
      basket.map { |item| total -= 0.75 if item == 001 }
    end
    total
  end

  def two_or_more_lavender_hearts? basket
    n = 0
    basket.each do |item|
      n += 1 if item == 001
    end
    n >= 2
  end

  def ten_percent_discount total, *arg
    if total > 60.00
      total = total - total/10
    end
    total
  end
end
```

Thanks to everyone for their help. I love the open-source nature of coding - threads just get better and better as people iterate over each other's solutions!