# Ruby - collection of methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have inherited a bunch of methods that are not wrapped by any classes or modules, and are just listed in an .rb file.  This was made possible due to the file being used inside a Cucumber test suite.  I want to take a collection of all these methods and iterate over each method call, doing some work on each one as they are called.

EX:

```
def call_all_methods
  method1
  method2
  method3(true)
  method3(false)
  method4('Y', true)
  method4('N', true)
  method4('Y', false)
  method4('N', false)
end
```

What i want to be able to do is wrap these all in an array and call them individually with a begin/rescue block around them

```
$all_methods.each do |method|
  begin
    method.call
  rescue Exception1
    handle_exception1
  rescue Exception2
    handle_exception2
  end
end
```

I've tried putting them all in an array using %w

```
call_all_methods = %w(...)
```

and that works but it makes the methods ugly to look at in the IDE

I've tried doing a readlines on the file, but the methods get executed while the file is being read.

I could create methods to wrap each call, but then I have a method to call another method (one line) which isn't right either.

I have looked at [[Ruby: methods as array elements - how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948910/ruby-methods-as-array-elements-how-do-they-work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948910/ruby-methods-as-array-elements-how-do-they-work) but neither of those solutions seemed like good solutions for what I'm trying to do, as it would dirty the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making an array of procs

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def execute_several(arr)
  arr.each do |method, *args|
    begin
      v = send(method, *args)
      puts "for method '#{method}': #{v}"
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      puts "for method '#{method}': #{e.message}"
      end
    end
  end

  arr = [
    [:class],
    [:rand, 20],
    [:Integer, "20"],
    [:Integer, 'cat']
  ]

  execute_several(arr)
    # for method 'class': Object
    # for method 'rand': 17
    # for method 'Integer': 20
    # for method 'Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "cat"
```

Here's an example of how that would be done within a class:

```
class Array
  def execute_several(arr)
    arr.each do |method, args|
      begin
        v = args ? send(method, args) : send(method)
        puts "for method '#{method}': #{v}"
      rescue TypeError => e
        puts "for method '#{method}': #{e.message}"
      end
    end
  end
end

arr = [
  [:reverse],
  ['first'],
  [:&, [2,3,4]],
  [:|, 'cat']
]

[1,2,3].execute_several(arr)
  # for method 'reverse': [3, 2, 1]
  # for method 'first': 1
  # for method '&': [2, 3]
  # for method '|': no implicit conversion of String into Array
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you could just wrap those methods in a class.

```
class MyMethods
    # all those methods that you have in that file
end
```

You could then list them all by doing

`all_methods = MyMethods.instance_methods(false)`

To execute them, you can do `all_methods.each {|m| MyMethods.new.send(m)}`

Comment: I had actually tried to implement this before, but the problem is that some of them have arguments.  The methods listed in the question are method calls, not method declarations.